# How to run normal sql queries in cakephp2 and get the results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp2  and I wanted to ask how can I run normal sql querys and get the results then
finally  set the result to the variable ?  when I run the script below I cannot get the the result and set it to the variable .

```
$results = $this->PvCount->query("SELECT
    dt,
    SUM(total_pv) AS Total
FROM
    pv_counts
WHERE
    curdate()
GROUP BY
    dt");
```

Comment: What exactly in $results. Have you var_dump that variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to write it correctly :

```
 $results = $this->PvCount->find
('all',array(
'fields'=>array('PvCount.dt','SUM(PvCount.total_pv) as Total'),
'conditions'=>array('PvCount.date '=>' curdate() '),
'group'=>array('PvCount.dt')
));
```

to get data from the .ctp :

```
foreach ($results as $result):
   echo  $result['PvCount']['dt'];
   echo  $result[0]['Total'];
endforeach;
```

hope it helps ...